# Zipping and moving SQL backups - Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, backups

I am having issues getting a script of mine to work and need some asstiance.

The goal of the script is to take SQL backups, ZIP them using 7zip, them move them to a NAS. After the move, the original backup is deleted, but not before confirming the name and size.

You can find my script [here](http://pastebin.com/5keB8v52).

If there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do or an already built script I could be pointed to, that would be great!

Comment: What are the issues you're having?

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://ServerFault.com

Comment: When it tries to ZIP, the folder is found, but it's failing to find any files within the folder that end with .bak.